# How to draw a vertical dashed line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a vertical dashed line (1,0) -- (1,3) but it does not work..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.9} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
   xlabel = {$\alpha$},
    ylabel = {$h(\alpha)$},
  xlabel style={ right},
  ylabel style={above },
]

\addplot [
    domain=-1.5:1.5, 
    samples=1000, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {1*x + 1*x^2};

\end{axis}

\draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (1,3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not directly related ... you use "ancient" version of `pgfplots`, recent version is 1.17 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

With use of the recent LaTeX installation and recent version `pgfplots` package (yours is very old, it is time to upgrade it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % it loads tikz too
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.17} % <----

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=center,
   xlabel = {$\alpha$},
   ylabel = {$h(\alpha)$},
  xlabel style={ right},
  ylabel style={above },
            ]
\addplot +[domain=-1.5:1.5, samples=100, thick, no marks]
    {1*x + 1*x^2};
\draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (1,3);  % <---
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't actually know that the OP has an old version of `pgfplots` installed, that `compat=1.9` is used in the code doesn't mean that the installed version is v1.9.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I know, so I like to encourage him/her to upgrade it.

Comment: I use overleaf and simply started with
 https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/pgfplots_package. Zarko, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside the `axis` environment:

```
\draw [dotted,->] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,3);
```

Comment: I used

```\draw [dotted] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,3);```
 
and this is what I need. 

Do you know by any chance how to make the scaling of the axes diasppear?

Comment: Asking for another question in an answered topic is not an appreciated behaviour ;) You may ask another question about that new problem that you have in order to avoid confusion for those searching for answers to similar questions.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am sorry.